# segue button to next viewcontroller throws error in xcode

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a tabbar ios application. I put (embed) NavigationController in one of the viewcontroller,then added one button and one new viewcontroller to pass. I dragged from button in first vc to new vc and select "push".
But following error message is thrown when I tab the button :

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'**

I really don't understand because I have already a navigation controller and also not added any additional code yet.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might connected the first VC as Push . I mean , Is there any RootViewController for navigationController..?

Comment: the rootviewcontroller is any viewcontroller in the project. I embed a navigationcontroller in this vc and segue to the next vc via button. should I add/set any controller from editor or code?

Comment: I made a very simple example and made sure the navigation conroller didn't effect if the rootviewcontrollers were not having navigationcontroller. But how can I add nav.controller form the later level of vcontrollers?

Answer (score 0):

You may not use push segue with a button that you have created yourself. Try using Modal segue instead.

Comment: but I need to use. I do not want to use modal sague. Furthermore, I really would like to know what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: When you are using push segues, the source which causes the segue (in this case a button) must be somehow related to the UINavigationViewController. Kindly try to find an online tutorial regarding push segues. @MuratCalim

Comment: I am not sure about your comment m177312. Because you will not see any problem when you do following ; 1-create a project empty, 2 - embed a navigationcontroller 3- put a button 4 - add another uiviewcontroller 5 - drag with ctrl from button to next uiviewcontroller and it works!